# Set color on collision?

Tags: color

A newbie question here - I'm doing a basic animation where the object is bouncing off multiple objects down the hill. What I want is to set a specific color for these object whenever the falling object collides with it. At the moment I'm just using keyframes to color these objects but this is time consuming.

Also If I'm duplicating the object which color has been changed then I have to delete the color setting and add a new one, otherwise the color will change for all these objects at the same time.

[image]

I was wondering if there is another way?